# how to synchronize local and remote database?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in SQL server on local computer, we have the same database on remote p.c  , i want to sync it with remote server, is there any script for SQL server or any plugin? Thank you.

OS: XP-PROFESSIONAL SP3
DATABASE : SQLSERVER 2008 EXPRESS

I want to synchronize the whole schema. And remote will be always correct.

Comment: Can you give us more information to assist you better. What is the OS environment & the database environment (whether its MSSQL or MySQL) you're using.. This will help us to advise you accordingly. :)

Comment: Are you looking to synchronize the schema, data, or schema + data across those environments? How does the data change? Do you only add rows or is data changed or deleted between systems? In the case of a conflict (local says B, remote says C), which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Writing update scripts that will synchronize two databases manually is quite a risky job. You can maybe try to compare these by creating scripts for all objects and then use a file compare tool to find the deltas between the two schemas and change it. But for even a bit larger databases I would not recommend this method since it’s quite easy to miss some change

using some third-party tool is probably the must here, so you can try [ApexSQL Diff](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-diff.aspx) or free [MS SSDT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ssdt/updated-sql-server-data-tools-for-september-2013?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20ssdtblog%20%28SQL%20Server%20Developer%20Tools%20Team%20Blog%29)

ApexSQL Diff can use database backups, script folders, source controls, and proprietary snapshots as data sources. It supports automation via CLI

*Disclaimer: I'm working for ApexSQL as a Technical Support Engineer*

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches. Either manually moving the structures/data in a one-time-effort or using automatically using Replication for continuous updates/synching.

For the simple manual approach, Save each table structure to a SQL file. Right click on the table, "Script table as" -> "Create To" -> file. Then on the DB itself, right click -> "Tasks" -> "Export Data" -> [If the remote db is accessible, you can move it here, if not, save to a file and import it on the other machine]

For the Automatic approach, each SQL Server is configured for Replication. The options vary widely. A good starting point is [the Chapter on Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) from the MS SQL 2008 Manual.

Comment: how to do replication on sql express , since express edition cannot act as publisher ,so what is the alternate in case we have express edition in both the servers.